# image not shown in dvi after latexing

Tags: image, latex, postscript

I include several images of eps format in latex. After latex command, there are some of the images missing in the dvi file. Not sure if it is related to the image size, most of the images missing have size around 83kB while those shown up have a size less than 40kB. After conversion from dvi to ps, the images are all back. Just wonder what is the reason causing the images missing in dvi file?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: I don't know the reason, but the same happens to me. Actually when using a custom frontpage, I can't see the frontpage in dvi, but works great in ps and pdf format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can remember, a dvi viewer cannot show eps file.  Just use `pdflatex` as the front-end instead of `latex` and view the resulting pdf file.

Checking `man xdvi` reveals this:

> Xdvi can show PostScript specials
>   by any of three methods.  It will try
>   first to use Display PostScript,
>   then NeWS, then it will try  to
>   use  Ghostscript  to  render the images.  All of these options
>   depend on additional software to work
>   properly; moreover, some of them may
>   not be compiled into this copy of xdvi.

So it would appear to be platform- and/or implementation-dependent.

Comment: Note that when using pdflatex, included vector graphics should be in pdf and not a postscript format.

Comment: Yes, my latex beamer files typically include anything from png to pdf where available.